# Sequence - Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\alpha$ - Calculus

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, solution-verification

Regarding:

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ and let $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ be a differentiable function, let $t \in [a,b]$, and consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_1=t & \\ 
x_{n+1}=f(x_n) & \forall n\geq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Suppose that there exists a point $\alpha \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.

Prove, while using MVT, that if there exists a $0 \le q <1$ such that $|f'(x)|\le q$ for every $x \in [a,b]$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\alpha$

--

I have tried to separate this question and prove it step by step:

1. Note that $f$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$, so it is differentiable and continuous function in every interval that is a part of $[a,b]$, in particular in $[\alpha,x_n]$, So by MVT, we get that there exists a point $d$ such that $\alpha<d<x_n$ and: $$f'(d)=\frac{f(x_n)-f(\alpha)}{x_n- \alpha}=\frac{x_{n+1}- \alpha}{x_n- \alpha}$$
2. We know that $|f'(d)\le q|$ so in conclude we get that $|x_{n+1}-\alpha| \le q|x_n-\alpha|$

I'm not sure that I did this part correctly, because I can't be sure that $\alpha < x_n$ to choose the interval $[\alpha,x_n]$ that I worked with. Also, I don't know if I can take $x_n$ as a part of the interval - can I?

3. I'm not sure, but I think that recursively I can say that
   $q^0|x_{n+1}-\alpha| \le q|x_n-\alpha| \le q^2|x_{n-1}-\alpha| \le ... \le q^n|x_1-\alpha|=q^n|t-\alpha|$ which means that $|x_{n+1}-\alpha| \le q^n|t-\alpha|$

I'd love to know if what I did so far is correct, and get some tips on what to do next.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done with the proof. For $\varepsilon > 0$ we let $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2q}$. Thus $|x_1 − \alpha| <\delta $ implies that $|x_{n+1} −
\alpha| < q^n \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2q} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$ for all $n > 0$. Hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n = \alpha$.

Fun fact:

You can make this claim even stronger. If $|f^{'}(\alpha)| <1$, then also $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n = \alpha$.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

No matter if $ x_n\le \alpha $ or $ x_n>\alpha$.

The MVT works in both directions
$$f(a)-f(b)=(a-b)f'(c)$$
and

$$f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$$

With the absolute value, we get the same result.
$$|\alpha-x_{n+1}|\le q|x_n-\alpha|$$
$$\le q^2|\alpha-x_{n-1}|$$

...

$$\le q^n|x_1-\alpha|\to 0$$
thus
$$x_n\to \alpha$$

Comment: Thank you, but what if $\alpha=x_n$?

Comment: @MathLover In this case, the sequence will be stationnary : $x_{n+1}=x_{n+2}=...=\alpha$.

Comment: I see, and why can the sequence be stationary? Thanks!!

Comment: @MathLover For example, if the initial value $t=\alpha$.

Comment: I do not see a contradiction in this case.

Comment: @MathLover I don't understand this last comment.

Comment: I mean, if the sequence is stationary, than the MVT still works here? I still get that $|x_{n+1}-\alpha| \le q|x_n-\alpha|$  ? I don't think so, because we get that $[\alpha,x_n] == [\alpha,\alpha]$